How to set velocity of animation in Android
I have a set of animations, I noticed that when each piece starts the speed is very fast, how can I adjust the execution speed?
I try this but the animation is too fast
val animator1 = ObjectAnimator
            .ofFloat(binding.logoAnimated,
                "translationX", 0f, -(width - point.x)).apply {
                repeatCount = 1
                repeatMode = ValueAnimator.REVERSE
            }

        val animator2 = ObjectAnimator
            .ofFloat(binding.logoAnimated,"translationX",
                0f, +(width - point.x)).apply {
                repeatCount = 1
                repeatMode = ValueAnimator.REVERSE
            }

        val animatorSet = AnimatorSet()
        animatorSet.playSequentially(animator1, animator2)
        animatorSet.start()


You can adjust the execution speed of your animations sing ObjectAnimator, you can set the duration property of each ObjectAnimator instance. This property determines how long the animation takes to complete in milliseconds
val duration = 2000L // 2000 milliseconds = 2 second


val animator1 = ObjectAnimator
    .ofFloat(binding.logoAnimated, "translationX", 0f, -(width - point.x))
    .apply {
        this.duration = duration  // Set duration for animator1
        repeatCount = 1
        repeatMode = ValueAnimator.REVERSE
    }

val animator2 = ObjectAnimator
    .ofFloat(binding.logoAnimated, "translationX", 0f, +(width - point.x))
    .apply {
        this.duration = duration  // Set duration for animator2
        repeatCount = 1
        repeatMode = ValueAnimator.REVERSE
    }


val animatorSet = AnimatorSet()
animatorSet.playSequentially(animator1, animator2)
animatorSet.start()


You can set an iterpolator in your ObjectAnimator instance. This determines the curve of the animation. A visual representation can be seen in this article. (not mine) https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-interpolators-a-visual-guide. It also comes with some code samples.
